# How can I call an already locked code block from witin the class again?

Tags: python, locking

I am working with locks within a class to avoid multiple threads adding the same elements to a list twice. However, my class gets stuck when I want to access a method protected by a lock from within the class itself.

The class looks like this (simplified, so it does not make much sense anymore):

```
import threading

class List(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def add(self, element):
        print("adding")
        with self.lock:
            if not element in self.list:
                self.list.append(element)

    def get(self):
        print("getting")
        with self.lock:
            # Try to get more elements, might fail
            if len(self.list) == 0:
                self.getFromDb()

            if len(self.list) > 0:
                el = self.list.pop()
                return el
            else:
                return None

    def getFromDb(self):
        print("getting from db")
        # Emulate an hardcoded database ;)
        self.add("i am new")
        # Here we will enter a block that is already locked by
        # the thread who called get() so my method waits
        # infinitely
```

So the following test file does not complete as it gets stuck when it wants to add new elements to the list:

```
list = List()
print("= 1 =")
list.add("hi")
print("= 2 =")
print(list.get())
print("= 3 =")
print(list.get())
print("= 4 =")
```

Output is:

```
= 1 =
adding
adding
= 2 =
getting
hi
= 3 =
getting
getting from db
adding
```

There you can see that all methods are working, but when a new element shall be added from `getFromDb` (called from the locked block inside `add`) who itself calls `add` again, the application cannot continue.

Are there other methods than just filling the list directly in `getFromDb` without using `add`? This would not be that nice, as `add` does checking for duplicates (already in this very basic example).

Comment: Are you looking for RLock instead of Lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a recursive lock. 
There is one in python's `threading` - [see here](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#rlock-objects).

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you need two versions of add()---one that acquires a lock and one that doesn't.  get() should call the version that doesn't acquire a lock since it already has the lock.

Alternatively, have you considered using an [RLock object](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#rlock-objects) which (based on my reading of the doc) keeps track of recursive attempts to acquire a lock within a thread?